# Tailwindcss responsive breakpoints are not working

Tags: tailwind-css

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container bg-green-400 md:bg-blue-400">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i go on developer mode on the browser and change the width the background color doesn't change at all. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` within head element.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your config.js file and run this code to check does it works.

`<div class="lg:px-20 md:px-10 px-0"><p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum </p></div>`